Could space tourism ever offer total solar eclipse viewings by traveling near the tip of the Moon's umbra as it's projected into space near Earth?
Since the Moon is always casting a shadow, a total solar eclipse is always happening somewhere in space. Could commercial spaceflight ever offer space tourists the ability to see totality around normal new moon phases?
I feel like the following things could be issues:

Relative velocity between the spacecraft's orbit and the umbral cone may make totality too quick to be interesting
Positional accuracy might be too precise or require too much ΔV (out of plane/too far from Earth)
Opportunities to view totality would need to be close to the new moon to avoid needing to go too far from LEO


Easier would be to create an artificial eclipse using a large disc some distance away.  Technically you could just use your finger, but there are effects on the edges which benefit the disc being a good distance away.

The area of totality travels at 1000-8000km/hr on the Earth’s surface which is a fraction of LEO orbital speed. Its ground track is not necessarily a great circle (unlike a LEO).
You will get a poor match between the totality ground track and any LEO (unless the totality happens to pass through the subsolar point).
If you want to maximize time in totality, you are better off using high speed aircraft than a LEO orbit.
However, if you are dreaming of space tourism, dream big and go above LEO. It opens other opportunities.
Travelling near the tip of the umbra provides only a brief eclipse, as opposed to travelling through a wide portion of the umbra at the same speed. And if you travel parallel to the axis of the umbra, the eclipse will last much longer than travelling transverse to that axis.
A trans lunar orbit could provide a path parallel to the umbra axis, and at much slower than LEO speed. This would provide much longer viewing. The ticket price would be proportionately larger.

In the sketch, the moon’s orbit is in black. The moon (and it’s umbra) are shown in multiple locations. The red line indicates the path the tip of the umbra takes as the moon orbits.
The green line is an elliptic Earth orbit of one lunar month period, coplanar with the moon’s orbit. If done just right, tourists could enjoy a prolonged solar eclipse every two weeks… and the possibility of a lunar transit of the Earth (?partial Earth eclipse?) or solar eclipse in between !
